How did the CBS 2024 presidential election exit poll define "state of democracy"?
According to this article by CBS News, one of the most important political issues for U.S. voters right now is the "state of democracy."

Early exit polls show the state of democracy and the economy are the
top issues for 2024 voters.
The economy is the top issue for Trump voters, followed by
immigration. And democracy is the top concern for the Harris voters,
followed by abortion — echoing some of the themes we've seen
throughout the campaign.

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/exit-polls-2024-presidential-election/
What does the phrase "state of democracy" mean in this context, and why are people concerned about it? I know what democracy is. Are people worried the U.S. is becoming more or less "democratic?" If so, what evidence supports this concern?

I mean from your own link: "About 7 in 10 voters (majorities on both sides) expect there to be violence related to the results of the presidential election."

There are multiple different questions asked at the end of the question body. What the phrase means is different from why people might be concerned about it is different from what evidence may support such a concern. It would be much better to ask them separetely.

@Philipp regarding your edit: the poll almost certainly did not define the term; pollsters normally just ask questions and refuse to clarify them if asked.  If the phrase is ambiguous enough for different respondents to interpret it differently then the poll is poorly designed.

The simple answer to the title question is that the exit poll did not define "the state of democracy". Those 4 words and nothing more were one of the choices of "which issue mattered most in your choice for president", with the interpretation up to the respondent.

I think a large part of the problem is that people think the US is a Democratic nation, when in reality it is a representative republic.  That's why the pledge of allegiance starts with "I pledge allegiance to the flag of the United States of America.  And to the REPUBLIC FOR WHICH IT STANDS..."

@264 I see your point, but I would label the issue of violence related to the election "politically motivated violence" instead of "state of democracy." I can see how a failure to create a fair election could motivate the violence, but the relationship is indirect, and there are other reasons why such violence would occur. I didn't see the relationship there when I was reading the article, but it makes sense to me after reading the answers.

@Nuclear Hoagie it looks like the title was edited. I recognize pollsters don't define their terms, but I figured asking people who follow US politics more closely than me would be able to provide at least some context into the meaning, which they did.


I know what democracy is. Are people worried the U.S. is becoming more or less "democratic?"

Yes people likely fear the U.S. is becoming a whole lot less democratic. The last time Trump didn't win the election his supporters violently stormed the capitol and involving several deaths, based on apparently completely made up claims of his that the "election is stolen", just because he didn't win.
The supreme court has, by Trump, been stuffed with cronies, which is relevant as they are not just there to ensure the constitutionality of government action, but also are able to essentially make law by reinterpreting law. An example is abortion which was ruled by the court to be a guaranteed right and which can now be illegalized, both of which is not founded upon some law that got democratic approval but upon the decision of a handful of judges, who interpret the constitution. Judges that are more and more handpicked not because they are neutral and professional, but because they are biased and who were confirmed despite good reasons not to. Like Kavanaugh was accused of sexual assault and Republicans didn't even bother to investigate. So one of the highest judges could be a criminal.
Furthermore, and probably even more importantly, these judges also argue that the president is basically above the law. Which makes a mockery of the idea of checks and balances, especially given that the impeachment process  (Trump is twice impeached), which is meant to keep a president in check, is apparently completely toothless if the party behind Trump simply doesn't care if the president is acting criminally, as long as it's their guy who's acting criminally.
Furthermore Trump has not really affirmed people in believing he will act according to the rule of law and not seek dictatorial powers. Asked about it he said he wants to be dictator but only on day 1. Which is one hell of a day to much for a democracy.
Also his stance on freedom of the press, everything negative is "fake news" regardless of journalistic standards and integrity, casts some serious doubts on the status of free speech.
And that's not yet talking about Project 2025 which seeks to make federal civil service jobs that are usually meant to be professional and independent of the government in charge (in that they are not changing when they enter or leave office), become political appointees. Which further casts big doubts on undermining checks and balances and corrupting democratic institution as partisan tools.
And that's on top of already existing democratic problems, like the fact that the voting system is from the start of the 19th century and that the electoral college has in recent years shown to be very problematic as it allows for someone to win an election without even having a plurality of the vote. Like none of the republican presidents in the 21st century have so far actually won the popular vote in their first term (Bush did so in the 2nd term though).
Or stuff like Gerrymandering where parties redraw the lines of voting districts in order to gain the most seats with the least amount of votes. You know if you lose a district add more of your opponents voters to it as so that you win all the other districts around and stuff like that.
Or voter suppression, like how you need to register to vote and might have to do so by identifying yourself, yet the U.S. has still apparently no registry of its citizens or a citizen id card, so getting one might cost money just to vote which disenfranchises poor people, which is fucked up because you're poor in a system you definitely have an incentive to change the system...
And that list is very long. There are unfortunately good reasons to suspect a decline in democracy in the U.S. which according to U.S. metrics has already declined from a full to a flawed democracy in recent years.

The idea that abortion was a guaranteed right was also just decided by "a handful of judges". Neither Roe nor Dobbs were democratic decisions.

You do understand impeached just means accused, not convicted. If someone claims with no evidence that the president did something and its dismissed, that's still considered impeached

This is a huge rant masquerading as an answer. A few issues already pointed out but, in the U.S., civil service jobs are most certainly not meant to be "independent of the government." There are three branches, civil service jobs are part of the executive branch and the President is the unitary head of that branch. The civil service employees are beholden to follow any legal policy the President implements. The civil service employees have a choice of implementing that policy, resigning or facing consequences related to their employment status.

-1 Because the 2022 Supreme Court merely ruled that abortion is up for states to control, that's it. They didn't ban it.

This answer seems to answer only half the question. It only mentions criticism of the state of democracy from the Democratic side. But it doesn't explain how the Republican side would interpret this question.

@Philipp Sorry, I'm not sure I get this remark. Like the question mentions that according to CBS exit polls show that democrats are most concerned with the "state of democracy", while republican care more about the economy. "Are people worried the U.S. is becoming more or less "democratic?" If so, what evidence supports this concern?". To which the answer is "less democratic" and I gave a list of topics related to that. Republicans apparently either don't care, see no necessity to act or embrace anti-democratic tendencies if it harms the political enemy, but that's not the question, is it?

This is the OP. Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I think the emotional language and debatable concepts help provide the context I was looking for, so I am accepting this answer.

@JonathanReez the answer does not appear to have ever said the Supreme Court banned it. The words they use are "can now be illegalized".

I can't tell you what CBS means, but we can take a crack at the notion.
Firstly, we should note that there is no hard definition of "democracy" in political science, not more than there is one for "fascism". Democracies and fascist regimes are characterised by a number of features or lack thereof, such as free and fair elections, the rule of law, separation of powers, freedom of speech, of religion, of association, of the press, and the protection of individuals/minorities against the arbitrary of the monarch/majority. One should also note that democracy isn't a binary opposite to fascism, it's a spectrum. A political system may have many democratic features alongside some non-democratic ones.
With all that in mind, the "state of democracy" can be understood as a measure of these those features, whether they're present in the United States and perhaps more importantly whether they're healthy or failing. This is something that can be methodically measured, though in the context of this poll it's probably more based on vibes.

There are a number of issues in US politics, like voter ID laws, like partisanship in the Supreme Court, like systemic racism, that some people take as a sign that US democracy is weakening, because they think their ability to vote has been or will be impeded (a threat or perceived threat against free and fair elections), because they're afraid the supremest judges of the land might align with the guy that appointed them rather than the Constitution (a threat or perceived threat against the rule of law and separation of powers), or because they're afraid their status as an immigrant might make them targets for state violence (a threat or perceived threat against the protection of minorities).
These are some of the reasons why progressives in general (though not exclusively) think Donald Trump is a danger to democracy, and there are certainly more. I don't think it's particularly constructive to go over all of them or debate them. The point is that, ultimately, Democrats (and a few Republicans) do think Trump is a danger for democracy, hence the fears for the "state of democracy".
A clear bipartisan issue is Jan. 6, an attempt to disrupt the certification of the 2020 election, seen by some on both side as a threat on free and fair elections, and on the democratic process in general.
This leads to the other side of the spectrum, where perhaps the biggest issue is election denialism, with a wide number of Republican voters who believe the 2020 election was stolen (thus is a perceived threat against free and fair elections). Some issues raised during the COVID-19 crisis, restrictions of movement (a threat or perceived threat on freedom of association/assembly), mask and vaccination mandates (a threat or perceived threat on protection against the arbitrary of the state), were perceived by some as an overreach of government on individual freedoms. This is a different, albeit just as vivid, take on the danger for the "state of democracy".

Nearly 20% of people who cited "the state of democracy" as their top issue voted for Trump - certainly people from different sides of the aisle were thinking about different things when answering. It's not solely that Democrats thought the Republican candidate would be bad for the state of democracy, the reverse is also true. About 10% of Trump voters cited the "state of democracy" as their top issue, but surely they don't feel he is the danger. The issue is more common among Democrats, but it seems clear not everyone interpreted the question the same way.

@NuclearHoagie Fair, and I've added on it

Nothing
That was a misleading exit poll question because it was ambiguous to the point it allowed both people who answered the poll and those interpreting the results to inject their own preferred meaning to it.
Consider that you can't tell what it means, and the people who were asked this question had to figure it out on the spot.
Voters on the left likely interpreted "state of democracy" meant January 6th riots, voter suppression.
Voters on the right can interpret that as politically-motivated criminal prosecution of Trump, government overreach, and political elitism.
Pundits did the same thing and spun the concern to support whatever candidate they believed would win.

What you suggest it means to different people still suggests it means something

@JoeW Most of the questions have a lean to them. "Economy" meant "the president needs to improve the economy." Nobody selected economy to express that the economy is great so they voted to maintain the status quo. This applied to all of them save "abortion" (which could be further cross-tabbed with state opinions), and this question.

That doesn't mean that the answers don't have a meaning.
